# Finding a match one after another

Tags: regex

How do I find multiple matches that are (and can only be) separated from each other by whitespaces?

I have this regular expression:

```
/([0-9]+)\s*([A-Za-z]+)/
```

And I want each of the matches (not groups) to be surrounded by a whitespace or another match. **If the condition is not fullfilled, the match should not be returned.**

This is valid: `1min 2hours 3days`

This is not: `1min, 2hours 3days` (`1min` and `2hours` should not be returned)

Is there a simpler way of finding a continuous sequence of matches (in Java preferably) than repeating the whole regex before and after the main one, checking if there is a whitespace, start/end of the string or another match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this pattern will meet your requirements *(provided that only a single space character separates your alphanumeric tokens)*:

```
(?<=^|[\w\d]\s)([\w\d]+)(?=\s|$)
    ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^    ^^^^
        (2)       (1)       (3)
```

1. **A capture group** that contains an alphanumeric string.
2. **A look-behind assertion:** To the ***left*** of the capture group must be **a)** the beginning of the line or **b)** an alphanumeric character followed by a single space character.
3. **A look-ahead assertion:** To the ***right*** of the capture group must be **a)** a space character or **b)** the end of the line.

See [regex101.com demo](http://regex101.com/r/yH2rC7).

---

Here is some sample data that I included in the demo. Each bolded alphanumeric string indicates a successful capture:

**1min 2hours 3days**

1min, 2hours **3days**

**42min 4hours 2days**

Comment: This is it! I've modified your version of regex (so now it looks like this: http://regex101.com/r/zS6xV4) and it's working for me just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "1min 2hours 3days";
boolean match = text.matches("(?:\\s*[0-9]+\\s*[A-Za-z]+\\s*)*");
```

This is basically looking for a pattern on your example. Then using `*` after the pattern its looking for zero or more occurrence of the pattern in `text`. And `?:` means doesn't capture the group.

This will will also return true for empty string. If you don't want the empty string to be true, then change `*` into `+`

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. I want to find the matches, not just validate the string.

Answer (score 0):

I've mananged to solve my problem by splitting the string using `string.split("\\s+")` and then matching the results to the pattern `/([0-9]+)\s*([A-Za-z]+)/`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error here the '*' will match all characters and ignore your rest
      /([0-9]+)\s*([A-Za-z]+)/

Change to

```
/(\d+)\s+(\w+)/g
```

This will return an array of matches either digits or word characters.  There is no need to always write '[0-9]' or '[A-Za-z]' the same thing can be said as  '\d' match any 0 to 9 more can be found at this cheat sheet [regular expression cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)